# How do I match the Android Gradle version?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

https://github.com/MobileSeoul/2016seoul-02

I opened open source on GitHub. However, the layout did not come out because the version was not correct in 'Gradle'. So when I did a search, I could see the advice of "keep the gradle numbers up to date". But I do not know how to set the Latest gradle number. Where can I find the Latest number?

---

> error message : All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found versions 23.4.0, 23.0.0. Examples include com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:23.4.0 and com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:23.0.0

---

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.runfive.hangangrunner"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    dexOptions {
        jumboMode true
        javaMaxHeapSize "2g"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
    //compile 'com.naver.maps.open:naver-map-api:2.1.2@aar' - Changed to Google Maps
    compile project(':decoviewlib')
    compile project(':calendarlib')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.+'
    //compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.4.0'
    //compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.7.2'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
    // dailyfragment에서 씀

    // Facebook interlocking
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.6.0'

    // Login with Naver
    compile files('libs/3rdparty_login_library_android_4.1.4.jar')

    // Card view
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.4.0'

    // font
    compile 'com.tsengvn:Typekit:1.0.0'

    // Subversion Support
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
}
```

---

[image]

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
   dependencies {
       classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
       classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0-beta1'
       classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.3.0-beta1'

      // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
      // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with the gradle version. One of your libraries pulls in `com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:23.0.0` as a transitive dependency. You can explicitly add it to the dependencies with version 23.4.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42374426/3998402) for more details

As of Android studio 3.0, it becomes much easier as it now shows a more helpful hint, so we only need to follow this hint.
for example:
[image: 2]]

> All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version
>   specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found
>   versions 27.0.2, 26.1.0. Examples include
>   com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:27.0.2 and
>   com.android.support:customtabs:26.1.0
>
> there are some combinations of libraries, or tools and libraries, that
>   are incompatible, or can lead to bugs. One such incompatibility is
>   compiling with a version of the Android support libraries that is not
>   the latest version (or in particular, a version lower than your
>   targetSdkVersion.)

**Solution:**
Add explicitly the library with the old version but with a new version number.
in my case `com.android.support:customtabs:26.1.0` so I need to add:

```
implementation "com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.0.2"
```

Note: don't forget to press sync now so gradle can rebuild the dependency graph and see if there are any more conflicts.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
I would like to ask you where to put the two codes you mentioned.

com.android.support:customtabs:26.1.0
implementation "com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.0.2"

Comment: this was just example read the linked answer and it would be easy to solve your current case.

as where to put it .. in build.gradle file